# 5-layer DNN in Keras trains slower using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I've written a 5-layer dense network in Keras 1.2 using tensorflow-gpu as backend and train it in my MacBookPro (CPU) and in a P2.xlarge instance in AWS (K80 - cuda enabled). Surprisingly my MacBookPro trains the model faster than the P2 instance. I've checked that the model is trained using the GPU in P2, so I wonder... why does it run slower?

Here is the network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(250, input_dim=input_dim, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(130, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(10, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[metrics.mae])
model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=batch, nb_epoch=epochs, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=2))
```

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem with a small network - and discovered that the wall clock time was largely due to CPU computations and data transfer between the CPU and the GPU, and specifically that the data transfer time was larger than the gains seen from doing GPU computations instead of CPU.

Without data to test on, my assumption is that similarly your network is too small to push the true power of the GPU and the reason you're seeing larger training time with the GPU is that your network takes more time to transfer the data between the GPU and CPU than it is gaining in performance increases from doing computations on the GPU.

Have you tried a noticeably larger network?